# overlay a fixed element over relative parents not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dom

Trying to solve an interesting CSS issue.

I am trying to render a modal that ends up having to be inside of a relative parent (container). I need it to be a fixed overlay, so that it will cover the entire viewport. The snippet included below is for brevity.

```
<nav>..</nav>
<div class='container'>
    <article></article>
    <div id="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Isn't working with:

```
position:fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index:(integer higher than highest z-index);
```

Open to JS or CSS fixes, any ideas?

EDIT: Just realized that this is only happening in Chrome. Updated and checked in Latest Safari and FF, this is a bug with Chrome I guess. Using Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94

Answer (score 3):

Both `absolute`/`relative` positioning are *relative* to the closest non-static parent element. On the other hand, `fixed` positioning is relative to the window/viewport. You could therefore add `position: fixed` in order for the modal to disregard the `relative` positioning on the `.container` element.

> [**9.6.1 Fixed positioning**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)
>
> Fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning. The only difference is that for a fixed positioned box, **the containing block is established by the viewport**.

```
#modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem,

It was being caused by a chrome bug that didn't like animations, specifically -webkit-animation-timing was causing the issue. If anyone else runs into this check for anything containing it in the DOM that has animations or transforms.